# Authenticating passwords against an LDAP

Tags: windows, security, ldap

I am a bit confused as to where passwords are stored within an LDAP. Many applications, eg. AD, seem to store passwords to allow users to log onto apps or computers. However, AD is open and can usually be viewed by anyone. So, where is the password? Can I pull passwords out of an LDAP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How secure is your password in LDAP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078156/how-secure-is-your-password-in-ldap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD stroes the password in an attribute called unicodepwd. This is a one way hash. Even if you can view it,you can not retrieve the password. Also this attribute can not be viewed with regular ldap searches. You have to use ldapi interface to retrieve it. Which means you have to be on the local machine.

Comment: One more Q: Does my PC retrieve the hash and compare it against the password I enter for my Windows logon (obviously hashing my PW with the same algo first)? Or does my password go in hashed format to AD, which then replies with a T/F after comparing to the stored hash?

Comment: When its AD (assuming domain login) its more complicated. It uses kerberos for the authentication. Your password or the password hash never traverse on the wire. First the client will request ASREQ (Authentication Request) and the ASREP (Authentication Reply) will be encrypted with the secret key generated from the password hash (from the AD store). The client receives the packet and generate the secret key from the entered password,using that it tries to decrypt. Only the key generated from correct password will be able to decrypt. If this succeeds other packet exchange will continue.

Comment: Have a look at this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)#Client_Authentication